# rearranging a nested list into {x,y}

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an issue, which is probably more of an syntax issue, but I have a nested list:

```
{{11, {1, 2, 3}}, {12, {4, 5, 6}}, {13, {7, 8, 9}}}
```

I am trying to get:

```
{{11, 1}, {11, 2}, {11, 3}, {12, 4}, {12, 5}, {12, 6}, ... ,{13, 9}}
```

I couldn't find anything relating to it in the Documentation Center and I couldn't manage to quickly rearrange this without copious amounts of Transposing and Selecting.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Join @@ Thread /@ {{11, {1, 2, 3}}, {12, {4, 5, 6}}, {13, {7, 8, 9}}}
```

> {{11, 1}, {11, 2}, {11, 3}, {12, 4}, {12, 5}, {12, 6}, {13, 7}, {13, 8}, {13, 9}}

## Performance remark

Should you have to process long list, it might be a better strategy to avoid constructing the mixed list

```
{{11, {1, 2, 3}}, {12, {4, 5, 6}}, {13, {7, 8, 9}}}
```

but to employ the pure arrays

```
a = {11, 12, 13}
b = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

because the latter two can be [packed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496).

Here a timing example:

```
n = 100000;
a = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, n];
b = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {n, 3}];
```

Your original dataset corresponds to

```
input = Transpose[{a, b}];
```

Now the timings:

```
input = Transpose[{a, b}];
r1 = Join @@ Thread /@ input; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = Flatten[
     {Transpose[ConstantArray[a, 3]], b},
     {{2, 3}, {1}}
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r1 == r2
```

> 0.11
>
> 0.00587
>
> True

You see, the method with `Flatten` performs almost 20 times faster, mostly because it only involves packed arrays (as input as was as intermediate results).

Answer (score 1):

```
Distribute[#, List] & /@ list
```

> {{{11, 1}, {11, 2}, {11, 3}}, {{12, 4}, {12, 5}, {12, 6}}, {{13, 
>      7}, {13, 8}, {13, 9}}}